# Anyone implemented Apple SKAdNetwork4.0 for Web Ads

Tags: skadnetwork

I am working at Taboola one of the largest discovery platforms in the world
We recently started to implement Apple SKAdNetwork4.0 for Web Ads solution for attribution tracking and reporting on IOS
here is Apple doc:
`https://developer.apple.com/documentation/skadnetworkforwebads/creating_an_attributable_ad_link`
We are facing many issues and it is very hard to get response from Apple support
Any change to the attribution link causing the ad impression not to sent
Like click redirect url is not working (ad impression is not sent)
Changing the order of the attribution params also not working
It's like they don't want this solution to work, anyone has experience with it?
Please refer you answers only to SKAdNetwork4.0 web to app
tx

We did all kind of tests on the ad impression click url' only the exact direct link to apple store is working, preventing us from monitoring our own ads clicks
We also open several support cases to apple which they replied once every 2 weeks very short with no intention to help at all